# Vertically aligning a div and proper scrolling overflow, is this possible?

Tags: css

I've discovered that I can have one or the other, but can't seem to figure out both.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="middle">
    <div id="middleinner"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS goes a little something like this (z-indexes set for something else on the page, left out here because it's irrelevant, plus there's a few commented out things as I tried to figure it out as I went along):

```
html, body{
        font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1em;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
}

#middle{
/*      display: table;*/
        display: table;
        height: 80%;
        width: 90%;
/*      position: fixed;*/
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 5%;
        right: 95%;
        bottom: 90%;
        color: #000;
        z-index: 0;
}

#middleinner{
        padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
        background-color: #F9F9F9;
        display: table-cell;
/*      display: inline-block;*/
        border-radius: 1.5em;
        vertical-align: middle;
/*      margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;*/
        text-align: center;
/*      position: relative;*/
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        z-index: 20;
}
```

Anyway, if I change middleinner's position to relative instead of absolute, I've got vertical alignment at the cost of proper overflow handling. If I set it to absolute, I've got proper overflow handling at the cost of vertical alignment.

Is there a pure-CSS way that I can handle this?

Comment: yes: http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/dFcAh

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a combination of `line-height`, `inline-block`, and `vertical-align` can do it.

```
#middle {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    height: 500px;
    line-height: 500px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
#inner {
    height: 50px;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.1em;
}
```

**[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/4027868)**

To have it work with a dynamic height element, you'll have to use some JavaScript, since you're using jQuery, I'll go with that. It's perfectly possible to use vanilla JS for this one too.

```
resize = function(el) {
    el.css({lineHeight: el.height() + "px"})
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $middle = $("#middle");
    resize($middle);
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        resize($middle);
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I use percentages since the middle div will re-adjust its height based on whatever the user sets their screen size to. Trying to adjust your CSS provided using percentages seems to break it. Am I missing something there, or would it still be possible using percentages?

Comment: @Skyline969: It doesn't break it for me, see the updated version of the demo.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear enough. I meant that I set the height based on a percentage, not a fixed size, since it occupies most of the page regardless of screen resolution. Here you've specified the width based on a percentage which is great and works wonders, but what about the height being based on a percentage? Example: Set the height and line-height to 90%, and it breaks.

Comment: @Skyline969: No, I'm afraid `line-height` cannot be relative to the container's height, you'll have to use JavaScript for that :(

Comment: Crud. I was hoping to not have to use JS for it, but I'm using plenty of jQuery anyway so perhaps it won't be that bad. How would I approach it from a JS aspect then?

Comment: @Skyline969: Well you'd probably watch for a resize event, to recalculate the new height of the `#middle` div, and set the line-height to exactly that same height. That would vertically center your `#inner` div.

Comment: @Skyline969: Added a quick example for your convenience :)

Comment: That worked great! However, if I have multiple lines inside of inner, they're all spaced apart that much.

Comment: @Skyline969: Correct. I assumed that was the only thing you had in there... If it isn't the only thing in there, wrap all of them inside of a container and call **that** #inner. The rest should fit in nicely.

Comment: I've already got that though, #middle and #inner, since #middle is a wrapper for #inner. Or are you telling me that I'd need something like #middle, #middleinner, and #middleinnerinner?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19186/discussion-between-skyline969-and-madara-uchiha)